# how can i open a ms word file saved in desktop by browsing from apex?

Tags: apex

I have browse a word file in apex, now i want to open the word file in MS Word from apex. I don't want upload the browsed word file in apex, just want to open it in ms word. How can i do it?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/63Q5t.png]

How to open this word file in MS Word form apex. Can any one solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

On top of my head, you can use [Zippex](https://github.com/pdalcol/Zippex), it was natively designed to zip and unzip files but can be used for reading and writing MS word file.

[image: https://github.com/pdalcol/Zippex]

This was demoed in 2018 DF session: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IMWS7N28hHs